# Override Field.tpl.php for a specific node/add form

Tags: theming, forms, commerce

**Basic Question**

In Drupal 7, you can override all the fields of a specific content type by changing the `field.tpl.php` file name to `field--YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE.tpl.php`

How can you override the fields that appear on the "node add form" for a content type?

---

**More Info**

I am using [Drupal Commerce Bulk Product Creation](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc) and with this module you create your nodes at yoursite.com/admin/commerce/products/add-bulk/PRODUCT_TYPE.

I want to over-ride the field.tpl.php file for this name, but I am not sure how to do it.

I know you can override the node.tpl.php for this "node add form" by using the following in your template.php file:

```
function YOURTHEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'commerce_bpc_create_bulk_form' => array(
            'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
            'template' => 'templates/add/node--add--bpc',
            'render element' => 'form',
            ),
    );
}
```

Is there a similar code that can be used to override the field.tpl.php file for this node add form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or one of its relatives by setting the [#theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#theme) key of the form elements.

Comment: Thanks! After reading the docs on hook_form_alter(), I think it should be this:  `function chapel_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array( 
        'FIELD_NAME ' => array(
            'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
           'template' => 'templates/add/from',
            'render element' => 'form',
   ),
        

    );
}
` but it doesn't work. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You return an array. The theme function should return a string.

Comment: Thanks! This is the code I am using: `function MYTHEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) { return string( 'FIELD_NAME ' => array( 'arguments' => array('form' => NULL), 'template' => 'templates/add/from', 'render element' => 'form', ), ); }  `. However, it returns an error saying that I have a double error. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: What's a double error?

Comment: You should be implementing the hook_form_alter() function, not creating a theme function. You cannot use a template to alter form items, you need to make the changes in PHP.

Comment: To: Oswalrd it returns a double arrow error. To: sheena_D: Shouldn't these changes be done in the theme (because different themes might use different field.tpl.php files)?

Comment: Please copy error messages literally, they are good search phrases to enter into a search engine. I think you get a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW". This comes from `string( 'FIELD_NAME ' => array(/**/))`. This is not a construct that PHP understands. Use [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) to render a render array into a string.